# Arduino MKRZero malfunctioned after trying to load a program

Tags: usb, mkrzero

I have an Arduino MKRZero that I tried to load the following program into:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 60
#define ledPin 4;

AudioFrequencyMeter meter;
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  meter.setBandwidth(70.00, 1500);
  meter.begin(A0, 45000);
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, ledPin, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  float frequency = meter.getFrequency();
  Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
}
```

After which, the Arduino IDE said: 
"Couldn't find a Board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected.  If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button after initiating the upload."

And windows gave this message:

[image]

The board is dead for all I can tell. The light still comes on when I connect it to my computer and when press reset, windows makes the "you just plugged something in" sound, but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: Maybe the board was dead before you programmed it? The LED is probably fed by the 5V supply. As long as this supply is not shorted, the LED will shine, but not tell anything about the rest of the electronics.

Comment: @Huisman No, I used the board to only light up the led before including the bit with the frequency meter. That worked just fine.

Comment: Did you change the baud rate of the serial port you were using to communicate with the device?

Comment: @Tyler I don't know what that means. No, I didn't do anything like that.